# Grand ou gros ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Peut-on donner un critère pour savoir lequel de ces deux adjectifs utiliser ? Par exemple, je dirais sans hésiter "une grosse tempête dans un grand verre d'eau" ou "une grande maison sous un gros nuage" et pas l'inverse... mais pourquoi ? Comment puis-je aider mes amis non-francophones indécis ?

Answer (score 6):

La notion de *gros* renvoie à celle de volume, alors que l'on est *grand* par la taille.

C'est  ce que vous avez mentionné intuitivement, car un verre est souvent perçu plus *grand* que *gros*.

Mais on trouve aussi bien *grande* que *grosse* pour une tempête :

> - la période des grandes tempêtes (la période où les tempêtes sont en haut de *[l'échelle de Beaufort](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27%C3%A9chelle_de_Beaufort)*),
> - C'est une grosse tempête qui nous tombe dessus (elle est grosse par rapport à notre embarcation).

Comment: Hmm... quand je bois un grand verre d'eau, j'ai l'impression que ce que je souligne c'est bien son volume...

Comment: Grand peut être la hauteur du verre servi, qui est lié au volume. Tu peux dire "je veux un gros verre d'eau", qui suppose qu'il soit plus bas qu'un grand, mais plus large qu'un petit.

Comment: @Ri49 C'est l'aspect du verre : une grand verre (qui contient un volume plus important) est plus haut que large (les chopes de bière sont là pour en témoigner), c'est l’œil qui décide ici, pas l'estomac.

Answer (score 4):

C'est extrêmement difficile de donner une réponse succincte à cette question étant donné qu'un très grand nombre d'emplois sont figés et plutôt arbitraires.

Ce qui peut aider c'est les connotations associées à ces adjectifs. Voici les principales (il y en a d'autres).

*Grand* :

- valeur, noblesse : un grand homme, un grand vin, les grands principes
- étendue : un grand champ, un grand ciel bleu, une grande réflexion, un grand magasin
- dimensions principales: une grande table, une grande tour, une grande perche
- quantité, qualité : de grandes ressources, une grande intelligence

*Gros* :

- intensité : un gros orage, un gros problème, une grosse claque
- émotion : un gros chagrin, un gros merci, un gros câlin
- dimensions auxiliaires : de gros doigts, un gros chat
- indélicatesse : un gros porc, un gros débile

Comment: (Sentez-vous libres d'améliorer les exemples et d'ajouter d'autres connotations.)