# Help me order the largest beer... la plus grande or la plus grosse?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I feel like I have a pretty good handle on the difference between grand and gros, but when asking for the largest, biggest beer in a bar, which is more idiomatic?

> La plus grande bière

- does this translate more to 'tallest beer' vs.

> La plus grosse bière

- the biggest beer?

I'm thinking maybe both are correct, but with the tallest/biggest distinction. But I'd love to hear from someone with more idiomatic advice about what usage I might encounter in the Francophone world.

Comment: See also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/grand-ou-gros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you won't be disappointed, both nominal groups will be understood and you will have what you want.

Secondly, the main meanings behind those two words are :

- **[gros](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gros)** :

  - it will have the meaning of big
  - but also the meaning of huge girth and volume.
  - It may have even the meaning of fat.
- **[grand](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grand)** :

  - will have the meaning of tall,
  - large number
  - but also all that come with being tall, a bigger mass than a smaller one
  - and even a high quality meaning as the size of your achievements.

---

So, if you order *"La plus grande bière"* what you could possibly have :

- a huge beer (which is what you want)
- a high quality beer
- a regular beer served in a very tall fancy glass

and *"La plus grosse bière"* :

- a huge beer (same as above)
- a regular beer in a large girth glass

I must add that in my understanding (I am French) *gros* bring a more familiar meaning than *grand*.

*grosse bière* may be more suitable in a **bar context** (use your *gourmand* eyes when saying it) while *grande* may be more appropriate in a **classy reception**.

Comment: N'hésitez pas à m'indiquer ce que je peux modifier si vous n'êtes pas d'accord.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are really idiomatic in France. Asking for the largest quantity regardless of the quality would be often frowned upon.

*La plus grande bière* might be understood as the greatest, the most famous one while *la plus grosse bière* seems just odd. *La plus grosse/grande bouteille de bière (que vous avez)* or *le plus grand verre de bière (que vous avez)* would be preferred.

One the other hand, *une petite bière* is [much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grande%20bi%C3%A8re%2Cgrosse%20bi%C3%A8re%2Cpetite%20bi%C3%A8re&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrande%20bi%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrosse%20bi%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpetite%20bi%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0), and doesn't mean the beer is specially small.

In any case, the size of a beer served at least in France is pretty standard, it is almost always a *demi* (originally half a *pinte*, now a quarter of a liter) and there is also the *pinte* (1/2 liter).

Bottled beers can be 0.375 liter.

Unlike in other countries like Belgium or Germany, larger glasses/bottles are very rarely served.

Comment: "Un p'tite bière" is an affective name, beers convey so much feelings !

Comment: @jlliagre Indead, both sounds weird to me. I would better say "Le plus grand **verre** de bière" to be clear.

Comment: @Random Thanks. I suggested "le plus grand verre" but "de bière" need indeed to be appended in the full sentence. Editing my reply for it to be clear.